# Setting up visual studio (maybe the latest version or the community Edition) for Linux server side development

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio

I am doing the server side development using C++ where I connect to the Linux boxes from windows using PuTTY and write codes using vim.
Due to the fact that VIM is not very good in navigating the code, I am thinking of setting up the visual studio for this purpose ..
So would like to know your experience in this case, if you have already done something similar.
I would really appreciate your guidance in this case.
Thanks.

Comment: How fixed are you on using Visual Studio? Personally, in the situation of writing code on Windows that should compile and run in Linux, I use NetBeans (although VS might just be fine) for editing and Subversion to roll out changes to the test system. The approach has some unprofessionalities in it I guess and it does not harness the IDE's full power but works nicely for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry for the late reply - I have been away - had a long holiday.
The reason for using Visual Studio is due to its intelliSense and also plus its quick code navigation capabilities that will allow speeder development. I am ok to use Netbeans as well.
Currently using VIm - Vim is good for faster typing, but it does not have inherent code navigation, intelliSense (C++) capabilities. These are quite helpful when developing codes for complicated code base.